# C++ Program Crashing

Tags: c++

Hi guys I am kinda new on c++ so I was writing a program and it works fine, but there is a problem. Every time I type number bigger than 100 my program crashes and I don't know why. Could anyone help me?

Program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i = 10;

  while(i > 0)
  {
    i--;

    int b = 0, c = 1, d = 0, e, number, how = 0, number1, start, to, number2, split1, split2, mass, start1 = 0, start2 = 0, number3, how1, number4, number5;

    cout << "\nIveskite skaiciu \n";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "\n";

    number1 = number;

    while(number1 > 0)
    {
        number1 = number1 / 10;
        how = how + 1;
    }

    how1 = how - 1;
    start = pow(10, (how - 1));
    to = pow(10, how);
    mass = to - start;
    number2 = start - 1;
    int split[mass][mass], numbers[mass], ok[mass];

    while(start1 < mass)
    {
        start1++;

        e = number2 + start1;

        numbers[start1] = e;
        split[start1][0] = e;
    }

    while(start2 < mass)
    {
        start2++;

        number3 = numbers[start2];

        d = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 1;

        while(d <= how1)
        {
            d++;

            split1 = number3%10;
            split2 = number3 / 10;
            number3 = split2;
            split[start2][d] = split1;
            number4 = b + split[start2][d];
            b = number4;
            number5 = c * split[start2][d];;
            c = number5;

        }

    if(number4 == number5)
    {
        ok[mass] = numbers[start2];

        cout << number4 << " " << number5 << " >" << ok[mass] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? What line does it crash on?

Comment: Please **indent** and **format** your code properly before posting it, it's unreadable as currently standing.

Comment: VLAs are not standard, and you can use the `log10` function to get the length of an integer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've formatted your code for you(edit pending review). In the future please do it yourself before posting. If you scroll down there's a preview window.
Please provide error message and on which line it crashes.

Comment: Thing is that the program itself stops working no crash line nothing and I don't know why. My guesses are that it crashes because of massives because they are too big but I if it is true I would like to know how could I make bigger massives. Thanks for code posting tips, I'll use them in the future

Comment: Did you run the code in a debugger? If not, do that first before making wild guesses.

Comment: Yes I did, same shit, and I get this error: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Comment: `split[mass][mass]` might become too large to put on the stack, can you try to allocate it dynamically?

Comment: "Yes I did, same shit" put some more effort in it please. At what line exactly does it segfault?

Comment: I don't really know how to do it... BTW http://postimage.org/image/t9g3lecc5/ I got this, I don't reall understand it...

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the first line in your program. Step through it line by line until the crash happens and then tell us where that was.

Comment: Dutt if I did it right when it crashes at int split[mass][mass], numbers[mass], ok[mass];

Comment: What's the value of mass? My guess is rather large, and you should take a look at how to allocate memory on the heap.

Comment: start = pow(10, (how - 1));
    to = pow(10, how);
    mass = to - start;

Mass depends on number you have written down

Comment: Use the debugger, it's what it's there for, and tell us what value mass is when it crashes.

Comment: It crashes when value is 900 but I can set to 20000 and it will work fine...

Comment: Thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me its the 2D array split that gets too large for your stack. You could probably try to allocate it dynamically as suggested here: [how to deal with large 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249829/how-to-deal-with-large-2d-arrays)